# I need the sequence in the list starting with 'b' and the next value is 'e' in SQL Server querying and eliminate all he other

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

Here is the screenshot, and I need a query which shows a value 'b' followed by 'e' and eliminates the rest of the rows.

Comment: You need a column to order by.

Comment: order by gives me all the b's and e's but need the sequence i need to only pick the 'b' value followed by 'e' and rest i have to ignore @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3270427/mcnets

Comment: Please see [mcve]  and [ask]

Answer (score 2):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "next value" unless a column specifies the ordering.

If you have one, then this is easy.  To get both, we'll use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(tripdetails) over (order by ?) as next_td,
             lag(tripdetails) over (order by ?) as prev_td
      from t
     ) t
where (tripdetails = 'b' and next_td = 'e') or
      (prev_td = 'b' and tripdetails = 'e');
```

The `?` is for the column that contains the ordering you want to use.

Comment: this is the actual query

Comment: select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(tripdetails) over (order by daily_vehicle_Receive_Date_local asc) as next_td,
             lag(tripdetails) over (order by daily_vehicle_Receive_Date_local asc) as prev_td
      from #test AS t
   
     ) t
where (tripdetails = 'b' and next_td = 'e') or
      (prev_td = 'b' and tripdetails = 'e');
 --ORDER BY t.daily_vehicle_Receive_Date_local

Comment: the above query is what i am sorting by and it is returning no values